# Camera viewfinder frame in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, camera

I am using SWIFT language and trying to take snapshot images from the camera viewfinder buffer. So far everything works well except for the image color. It seems incorrect or being swapped. Below is the code snippets where I set the video settings and capturing the image frames

```
func addVideoOutput() {

    videoDeviceOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    videoDeviceOutput.videoSettings = NSDictionary(objectsAndKeys: Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA), kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey) as[NSObject: AnyObject]

    // kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB tested and found not supported
    videoDeviceOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

    videoDeviceOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: sessionQueue)

    if captureSession!.canAddOutput(videoDeviceOutput) {
        captureSession!.addOutput(videoDeviceOutput)
    }
}

/* AVCaptureVideoDataOutput Delegate
------------------------------------------*/
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    sessionDelegate ? .cameraSessionDidOutputSampleBuffer ? (sampleBuffer)

    // Extract a UImage
    //var pixel_buffer : CVPixelBufferRef?
    let pixel_buffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixel_buffer, 0);

    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    var baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixel_buffer);

    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    var bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixel_buffer);
    // Get the pixel buffer width and height
    let width : Int = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixel_buffer);
    let height : Int = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixel_buffer);

    /*Create a CGImageRef from the CVImageBufferRef*/
    let colorSpace: CGColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue)

    var newContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo)

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixel_buffer, 0);

    // get image frame and save to local storage
    var refImage: CGImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(newContext)
    var pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(refImage))

    var image: UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: refImage)!;
    self.SaveImageToDocumentStorage(image)
}
```

As you can see one of the comment line in the addVideoOutput function, I tried the kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB format but it says not supported in iOS???

I kinda suspect the video format is 32BGRA but the color space for the image frame is set with CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), but I could not find any other suitable RGB format for the video setting.

Any solutions or hints are much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I found the cause and a solution. Just in case anyone experiences the same problem. Just change the bitmapInfo as follow: var bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst.rawValue) | CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Little

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause and a solution.

Just in case anyone experiences the same problem. Just change the ***bitmapInfo*** as follow:

```
// let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue)

var bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst.rawValue) | CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Little
```